# How to insert a row at a specific index in a SQL database table using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sqlcommand

I have created a SQL database named: **DateTimes**.

The database is now filled in with this information seen on this image:
[image: See the database table here]

As seen in the DateTime column, we can see those DateTime values in ascending order:

```
201005011600
201005011630
201005011645
201005011700
```

Now comes the problem, I wonder how to do. As we can see the rows are in DateTime ascending order and now I have a new record that have this DateTime that I want to add to the table:
**201005011615**

The code I have so far below only ADDS a row at the very end of the table.

**I do have 2 questions here:**

1. I now want to insert this record in the correct row which will be the second row in the DataTable. Which means that this record will be inserted at the correct index in the Table (DateTime ascending order)
   How is this possible to do?
2. Looking at the code, I use: `comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter...` 5 times. What I wonder here is since I could have many thousands of columns later. If there will be a faster way to `.Add` all info for all columns here in some kind of batch here instead. Which would mean, 1 .Add, instead of 5 .Adds?

   ```
    void insertvalue()
    {
        string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
        string cmdString = "INSERT INTO DateTimes (DateTime,F1,F2,G1,G2) VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4, @val5)";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
            {
                comm.Connection = conn;
                comm.CommandText = cmdString;
                comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@val1", 201005011615));
                comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@val2", 0.05044));
                comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@val3", 0.05044));
                comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@val4", 0.05044));
                comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@val5", 0.05044));
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    int i = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (i != 0) { MessageBox.Show(i + "Data Saved"); }
                }
                catch (SqlException ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
            }
        }
    }
    static private string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\andre\\source\\repos\\TestDatabaseCreation\\DatabaseTest.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
    }
   ```

Comment: Database tables are, and I can't say this strongly enough, **NOT ORDERED**. Ordering is **ONLY** a function of the `ORDER BY` clause you use when selecting.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Does this mean, that one should not insert a row in the middle of 2 other rows? and instead actually add the row at the very end of the table and then in the very end `ORDER BY` the `DateTime` column somehow?

Comment: You don't have any choice on where a row is inserted... you order the data when you retrieve the information. Thats just how databases work.

Comment: @Dale If I understand correctly. Then I will just `.Add` as I do in my code. That is the correct way to add data to the table which means that it can be saved in a wrong DateTime order? The thing is that later, this database will take up 100 GB of memory on the harddrive and I need to read this DataBase from top to bottom in DateTime ascending order without putting anything in to RAM. Then the database must be sorted somehow already?

Comment: Welcome to [Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: You don't have control over how SQL Server reads (or stores for that matter) data from the disk. You tell it what you want, and it delivers it in the best way it can. It may or may not cache some in RAM and/or temp tables on disk. Thats determined by the resources available to it. And unless you are pulling 1 record at a time, pulling 100GB into a C# app is going to use RAM as well. Anyway the normal way to approach database performance is first to design your system so that its logically correct, then address performance issues if they arrive.

Comment: I see, I think I get a hang of the idéa here then. So I will just store/.Add the rows to the table. Next problem is in what way I want to retreive the information. As `LarsTech` mentioned, I should use indexes in somehow for each row, which I can call upon later. I then wonder if I somehow could use `DateTime as in 201005011615` as an index and in that way I could iterate DateTimes in ascending order and return those rows? I am new to this so I am not sure how to add the index for each row.

Comment: Should I manually for example put: `201005011615` in the `id` column which I then could use as the index column?

Comment: Indexes are a complete complex topic in themselves, you'll have to do some research to gain the necessary understanding. You can index on pretty much any column - whatever you do, don't put your date in the id column, keep the id as being auto-generated otherwise you could introduce other complexities.

Comment: Thank you Dale, I was just reading the `Indexes` link above carefully. I did understand from the link this command for example: `SELECT Title, HireDate FROM HumanResources.Employee WHERE EmployeeID = 250` So one can use the `Employee` column for example or any column as you mention. I then get the idéa here and one should construct the indexes carefully etc. I will then leave the `id` column as auto-generated as it is now. Thanks for that info too. I will read more about indexes then and I thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Agree with above comments. You sort on data access in query. Additional indices are useful but not critical on small-ish databases. Good thing to learn but get your code the way you want first. As far as #2, you really should have a general class for database access (google "data access layer"). Personally, I like passing a dictionary of parameters to my database call functions. Regardless of what you do, you won't trim lines much as you still have to type out all those keys and values.

Comment: @Mark that is very good tips for me. I will first focus on building the basic structure first to create this database with a well choosen index column. Then in the next step try to see how I can sort/access in query in the best possible way, update this database etc. That sounds like a plan I also have in my head, using a dictionary with parameters and create classes that work with this database in all needed ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about how you will query the data in that table.  If it is the case that you will ALWAYS want to retrieve the data in DATE order - and also that the DATE is always a reflection of the date and time that you inserted the row, then defining a CLUSTERED index on the DATE column would be appropriate.

You will then generally always add rows to the end of the current page (and then get the next contiguous page on disk) and keep adding to the end of that.  Your queries by DATE will be efficient as they will be able to find a starting page and scan contiguously from there to the end of your date range.

NOTE - SQL Server will ALWAYS read the page into memory first before sending it to your client application - that's just the way it works. There is no mechanism to stream the pages from disk directly to your client application.   But, don't worry about that as it is as efficient a process as you can get.

Comment: Yes, I think the only requirement in this scenario would be a way to iterate through a `datetime range` and then if accessing each `datetime` using a query that would actually then work and it is not necessary that the rows are in order. I will look into `CLUSTERED index on the DATE column`. A Question there. You mention that SQL Server will ALWAYS read the page into memory. What does this mean if my database is 100 GB. Does that mean that I need 100 GB of RAM?

Comment: There was another question which should be the same. I will also need to add new columns dynamically in the table now and then. Normally the columns are grouped like: `F1, F2, F3` and `G1, G2, G3` etc. Here I thought about having all `F` columns after eachother and all `G` columns after eachother. But it is the same princip here. It is okay to add them like: `G1, G2, G3, F4, F5, G4, G5` like this and use queries here as well? `(I will always only add one row at a time to the database or change values on one row at a time in the database)`

Comment: When the DB is 100GB in size then SQL Server will start at the first pages, read those in and start to send them to the client, then as more pages are needed the last touched pages are removed from memory to make space.  You do not need 100GB of memory.

Comment: For the columns, again, SQL Server will decide where on the page to store them.  There is some structure based on the data types- but SQL Server manages that itself and you do not need to worry.

Comment: That sounds good. So I just add columns and for example use a Query to include all columns that `.Contains('G')` for example since those columns represents one kind of data?

Comment: Your second question needs more information - where is the source data values coming from?   Your code example is focussed on 1 value that you have single values for  - it depends on where you generate the source data as to what is the best method.

Comment: The source data values are actually coming from functions that do calculations. So initially the values that I store in the database are produced in the RAM memory(String, double variables). So sometimes other type of values are created. To make it simple. For example column A1-A5 are about cars. B1-B5 are about airplanes. Then I will add more columns C1-C5 that are about trains. But suddenly, I need to add a few more columns after a few days about cars. A6-A10. Then it is okay to just `.Add` those in the same fashion as the rows and query all columns that .Contains the letter: `A` in them?

Comment: Your approach to the "Parameters.Add" is correct. The only caveat I'd mention is that if you add more columns, you need to use an ALTER TABLE command before trying to insert - the columns must exist before inserting and also be aware that if they are not permitted to include NULL  (i.e. defined as NOT NULL) then you need to define a DEFAULT constraint for those columns as well so that the existing rows are updated with a default value

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did manage to create this code earlier today. So I have a function that have added new columns to the existing table. I tried with this command: `SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE [DateTimes] add [H2] float default -999999 NOT NULL")` So there I added a `H2` column as a test. So first is to add a column. Then second is to insert values for that now existing column. Sorry for all my beginner questions :)